# BigQuery avoiding multiple subqueries

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

We are working on an application that stores requests in one table, and responses in another (of course). We can have multiple responses per request, and we store the request ID on both tables.

Originally, I thought we could use a left join from requests -> responses to count how totals of each matching criteria:

```
SELECT source, COUNT(*) as requests, COUNT(responses.request_id) as responses
FROM DATASET.requests
LEFT JOIN DATASET.responses ON requests.id = responses.request_id
WHERE source = "source1"
GROUP BY source
```

There are 70 requests matching the WHERE criteria, and 30 responses matching this criteria. The expected output is: "source1, 70, 30".
Ive since learned more about JOIN behavior, and instead we get "source1, 259, 207". There is repeated IDs on both sides.

The only way Ive been able to get my desired result at all has been to create one giant query, and multiple full subqueries which match within the ID set filtered by the given criteria. Then using that filtered ID set to really pull our fields, stats, etc.

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT COUNT(*) as responses FROM DATASET.responses
  WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM DATASET.requests WHERE source = 
  "source1"))
  ,
 (SELECT source, COUNT(*) as requests
  FROM  PUBDATA.requests
  WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM DATASET.requests WHERE source = "source1")
  GROUP BY source)
```

This just seems terrible. I have tried using a CTE to gather the list of IDs we want, and using WHERE id/request_id IN (cte.id) but this apparently isnt possible unless we JOIN on cte, which again produces the wrong and multiplied results.

As we want to add additional stats to our query which will require further WHERE clauses, I am afraid this monster will continue to grow and is difficult to implement.

Please let me know if there is a better way to do this. Thanks!

Edit - Example schema as requested
**Requests**

```
id (String), source (String), partner_ids (Integer array), user_agent (String), timestamp (Timestamp), ...
```

**Responses**

```
request_id (String, from requests.id), partner_id (Integer), is_billed (boolean), price_charged (float, null if is_billed = false), response_categories (String array, not from requests), ...
```

The challenge is we must mainly query the Requests table to get an ID value list that matches our criteria, then query stats (such as counts, count where is_billed, etc..) on each table for one consolidated report. We may also need to pull the ID pool from criteria on each table (E.g. where  requests.source = 'source1' and responses.response_categories IN 'action')

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want with `union all` and `group by`:

```
select source, sum(requests) as requests, sum(responses) as responses
from ((select source, count(*) as requests, 0 as response
       from dataset.requests
       group by source
      ) union all
      (select source, 0 as requests, count(*) as responses
       from dataset.responses
       group by source
      )
     ) rr
group by source;
```

This does the calculation for all sources.

EDIT:

For the revised version, just use an additional `join`:

```
select source, sum(requests) as requests, sum(responses) as responses
from ((select source, count(*) as requests, 0 as response
       from dataset.requests rq
       group by rq.source
      ) union all
      (select rq.source, 0 as requests, count(*) as responses
       from dataset.responses r join
            (select distinct rq.id
             from dataset.requests rq
            ) rq
            on r.id = rq.id
       group by rq.source
      )
     ) rr
group by source;
```

If there is at most one response per request, you can shorten this to:

```
select rq.source, count(*) as requests, count(r.id) as responses
from dataset.requests rq left join
     dataset.responses r
     on r.id = rq.id
group by rq.source
```

Comment: Thank you but I also do not think this will work. Ive added clarification that the source field only exists on the requests table - the ID column is the only common intersection between them.

Comment: The update gives me (source1, 70, 207). So it is still multiplying the responses count, which should be 30.

Comment: @EvanTestvoid . . . You should really clarify the question with sample data.  You are not looking for the *number of responses*.  You are looking for the *number of requests with a response*.  These are rather different calculations.

Comment: That is incorrect. We want an independent count of requests, and responses, which are with ID values within a pre-filtered ID set, and then sorted together by ID and their associated column values in either table. To re-iterate there is a total of 70 entries in requests, and 30 in responses. That is the table size of each.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am misunderstanding something, why don't you just count each and join on id?

```
WITH
    sources
    AS
        (  SELECT COUNT (*) source_cnt, id
             FROM dataset.request
         GROUP BY id),
    responses
    AS
        (  SELECT COUNT (*) AS response_cnt, id
             FROM dataset.responses
         GROUP BY id)
SELECT source_cnt, response_cnt, sources.id
  FROM sources INNER JOIN responses ON sources.id = responses.id;
```

You could modify this to a full outer join if you want to keep all records:

```
WITH
    sources
    AS
        (  SELECT COUNT (*) source_cnt, id
             FROM dataset.request
         GROUP BY id),
    responses
    AS
        (  SELECT COUNT (*) AS response_cnt, id
             FROM dataset.responses
         GROUP BY id)
SELECT COALESCE (sources.id, responses.id) AS id, source_cnt, response_cnt
  FROM sources FULL OUTER JOIN responses ON sources.id = responses.id
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I am slightly confused by what you want to see in the end and I also do not fully understand how you have 70 requests and only 30 responses, if a single request can have multiple responses. Do you mean that some requests can have 0 responses? Or are you counting Distinct responses?

In case you wish to count the total number of requests and the total number of responses related to those particular requests, I believe this slight modification to your code should work:

```
SELECT source, COUNT(DISTINCT id) as requests, COUNT(responses.request_id) as responses
FROM `dataset.requests` as requests
LEFT JOIN `dataset.responses` as responses ON requests.id = responses.request_id
WHERE source = "source1"
GROUP BY source
```